# Installed Mojave, then my mac couldn't start the next day, now it asks to install Mojave again

Tags: high-sierra, upgrade, mojave

From High Sierra, I was prompted to upgrade to Mojave; did that, successfully completed (I guess, no errors were reported or something, but I don't remember if I restarted my laptop at that point. Moreover I didn't check if the version was upgraded in "About this Mac".).

Next day, I try to start my laptop, nothing... Eventually it says there was a problem finding the launcher or something. Laptop started successfully (phew!), and High Sierra is still installed.

Now, it asks me to upgrade to Mojave again, but I am afraid. What are the risks in accepting to upgrade? What should I do? Maybe I could stick to High Sierra...

Comment: Mohave is a big download and, depending on your connection, can take a while. Even a point update can take 30 minutes on my 15Mb connection. Is it possible you downloaded it but didn't let it install at that point?

Comment: @JRobert, I gave it all the time in the world..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What should I do?

If it were me, and my machine was running at this point, I'd backup the disk, then separately backup my home folder, and put those media aside. Then I'd redo the upgrade.